# Is it possible that Salesforce could return the 15 char Id and not the 18 char Id via the API intermittently

Tags: api, soap-api, integration

Is it possible that Salesforce could return the 15 char Id and not the 18 char Id via the API intermittently?

We have an integrated SFDC with a MA platform using CastIron. Been working fine, except we have some isolate incidents where the MA platform has duplicates. We have narrowed this down to Account Id. We have sent them two, once instance with the 15 and one incident with the 18. We have checked the SOAP logs and get see we sent them 18.

Comment: Are both records created using the same API version of your integration? Was one record created several years ago, before they implemented 18-character IDs for the API?

Comment: Nope, since we built the integration and put it live it has not changed (to the best of our knowledge)

Comment: It's been live only since Feb 2015

Comment: Hmm... As far as I know, it should *always* return an 18-character ID. I'm all out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Found the cause. Someone had manually loaded data into the MA platform which they exported from Salesforce via a report hence getting the 15 Len Id